# Applying Mean filter on an image using java

Tags: java

When I give it a picture with salt and pepper noise it returns an image loosing all details and I don't know what's wrong with my code:

```
public class Q1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("task1input.png"));

        //get dimensions
        int maxHeight = img.getHeight();
        int maxWidth = img.getWidth();

        //create 2D Array for new picture
        int pictureFile[][] = new int [maxHeight][maxWidth];
        for( int i = 0; i < maxHeight; i++ ){
            for( int j = 0; j < maxWidth; j++ ){
                pictureFile[i][j] = img.getRGB( j, i );
            }
        }

        int output [][] = new int [maxHeight][maxWidth];

        //Apply Mean Filter
        for (int v=1; v<maxHeight; v++) {
            for (int u=1; u<maxWidth; u++) {
                //compute filter result for position (u,v)

                int sum = 0;
                for (int j=-1; j<=1; j++) {
                    for (int i=-1; i<=1; i++) {
                        if((u+(j)>=0 && v+(i)>=0 && u+(j)<maxWidth && v+(i)<maxHeight)){
                        int p = pictureFile[v+(i)][u+(j)];
                        sum = sum + p;
                        }
                    }
                }

                int q = (int) (sum /9);
                output[v][u] = q;
            }
        }

        //Turn the 2D array back into an image
        BufferedImage theImage = new BufferedImage(
            maxHeight, 
            maxWidth, 
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        int value;
        for(int y = 1; y<maxHeight; y++){
            for(int x = 1; x<maxWidth; x++){
                value = output[y][x] ;
                theImage.setRGB(y, x, value);
            }
        }

        File outputfile = new File("task1output3x3.png");
        ImageIO.write(theImage, "png", outputfile);
    }
}
```

Comment: Format code and remove unused prints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getRGB "Returns an integer pixel in the default RGB color model (TYPE_INT_ARGB)" so therefore you have to extract the R, G, and B and add them separately; then put them back together. One way is this

```
int pixel=pictureFile[u+i][v+j];
int rr=(pixel&0x00ff0000)>>16, rg=(pixel&0x0000ff00)>>8, rb=pixel&0x000000ff;
sumr+=rr;
sumg+=rg;
sumb+=rb;
```

then to put them back together

```
sumr/=9; sumg/=9; sumb/=9;
newPixel=0xff000000|(sumr<<16)|(sumg<<8)|sumb);
```

Comment: when i did this it improved the details alot but it didnt remove the salt and pepper noise it somehow made it blur so it is not seen clearly as before is that considered correct ? @gpasch

Comment: depends on the image- yes blur is the effect - you may try median filter instead