# What am I doing wrong with my image denoising method?

Tags: java, image

I've been trying to denoise my image by using a median filter as described in [this article](http://www.codeding.com/?article=10)

I'm only doing one pass until I get this thing working. The result is largely a washed out image, as seen below.

A minimal working version of my code is below:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Denoise {

public static void main(String args[]) {
        String directory = "C:\\Users\\Speedy Octopus\\Desktop\\Place Car Folders Here\\Original\\15.JPG";
        BufferedImage image = ImageUtility.loadImage(directory);

    for (int iterationCount = 0; iterationCount < 1; iterationCount++){ 
        for (int i = 1; i < image.getWidth()-1; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < image.getHeight()-1; j++) {
                image.setRGB(i, j, getMedianPixelValue(image, i, j));
            }
        }

    }
    String directory2 = "C:\\Users\\Speedy Octopus\\Desktop\\Place Car Folders Here\\Original\\152.JPG";
    Controller.saveImage(image, directory2);
}

public static int getMedianPixelValue(BufferedImage image, int i, int j) {
    int[] surroundingPixels = new int[8];

    int iter = 0;
    for (int q = i-1; q<=i+1; q++) {
        for (int r = j-1; r<=j+1;r++) {
            if (!(q == i && r == j)) {
                surroundingPixels[iter] = image.getRGB(q, r);
                iter++;
            }
        }
    }

    Arrays.sort(surroundingPixels);

    int medianIndex = surroundingPixels.length/2;
    int medianPixel = surroundingPixels[medianIndex];

    return medianPixel;
}
```

}
[image: This is my starting image]

[image: This is my result]

Answer (score 0):

As I answered in this question [Applying Mean filter on an image using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40981913/applying-mean-filter-on-an-image-using-java/40983999#40983999) getRGB "Returns an integer pixel in the default RGB color model (TYPE_INT_ARGB)" so you have to extract and remove the alpha (A) component before you do any comparisons:

```
pixel=image.getRGB(i, j)&0x00ffffff;
```

in the media sorting etc

And you can extract the R, G, and B and process them separately, or do the comparison on the whole pixel RGB - you can experiment either way.